# I paid a fradulent bill via venmo, canceled payment with supporting bank and venmo, bank stopped payment, venmo didn't. Am i liable ro venmo?

Tags: liability

Suppose a person A canceled fraudulent transaction that A  made via Venmo with both venmo and A's bank.  Suppose the bank stopped payment, but Venmo didn't.  Suppose that Venmo now wants payment from A.   Is A  liable to Venmo?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer if you indicate the relevant jurisdiction: that is A's country and if a federal country such as Canada, the US, India or Australia, the state or province. It will also help a bit if you indicate in general terms why the transaction was fraudulent, and whether Venmo had reason to know of the fraud.

Comment: As edited, this aks what the law requires, not or specific legal advice. It should not be closed as asking for specific legal advice

Comment: Good question. I suspect that the contract/TOS with Venmo and UCC Article 4A govern, but don't know the answer.